# Find the underlying field from a query/view field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

Why?
I am trying to dynamically find where foreign keys points. For this I search in information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE. It works fine for tables, but not for views.

Views are referenced in information_schema.VIEWS, the view_definition field exposes the query.
I think that this is the only place I will find information about where view fields comes from, right?

Then, I would search for my field name between the SELECT and the FROM. If it is an alias, get the table field name and the table name (and resolve the table if it is an alias).

Last complication, the view can refer to another view, then the code will have to be recursive.

Let's take an example (view name is vw_mandates_articles):

```
select ma.*, a.id_articles_unit, a.id_articles_category from mandates_articles ma
left join articles a on ma.id_article = a.id
```

The way it is stored in the VIEWS table is:

```
select `ma`.`id` AS `id`,
  `ma`.`id_mandate` AS `id_mandate`,
  `ma`.`id_article` AS `id_article`,
  `ma`.`unit_price` AS `unit_price`,
  `ma`.`description` AS `description`,
  `a`.`id_articles_unit` AS `id_articles_unit`,
  `a`.`id_articles_category` AS `id_articles_category`
from (`ste`.`mandates_articles` `ma`
  left join `ste`.`articles` `a` on((`ma`.`id_article` = `a`.`id`)))
```

my inputs are:

- the view name (vw_mandates_articles)
- the field name (id_articles_category)

the expected output:

- the field table (ste.articles)
- the field name (id_articles_category) //could be same as input but not necessarily

I am not asking someone to write it for me, I just want to validate the approach before digging.

Any thoughts? Good/bad approach, alternatives?

Thanks in advance for your lights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Views only have fields stored in the query in the information_schema.VIEWS table.

---

No there's no better way than exploding etc. in the query...

---

I wouldn't recommend to make recursive views. What's sure is that it'll be slow (mysql ***will*** have to store the temporary result(s) on the hard disk what's really not improving performance).

Even if it isn't best practice, I'd tend to increase redundancy and get the data by using one single query (with maximal 1 subselect).

Comment: I don't get how I would retrieve the underlying table/field with your code, can you detail a bit more?

Comment: @y0uri fixed my answer, misunderstood your question ;)